# Unexpected result in a LINQ to Entities query

Tags: c#, entity-framework, group-by, linq-to-entities

I have following Entities in my `DbContext`:

[image]

I wrote following LINQ to Entities query in LINQPad to find all areas that an `order` passes(An `order` passes some areas to produced, an area may repeat):

```
OrderItems.Include("NominalRoutings.OperationCatalog.WorkCenter.AreaSpecification")
          .Where(x=>x.Id == 799730)
          .Select(r=>r.NominalRoutings.Where(t => t.OperationCatalog.IsActive)
                                      .Select(t=>new
                                                    {
                                                     AreaTitle=t.OperationCatalog.WorkCenter.AreaSpecification.Title,
                                                     t.ItemSequence
                                                    })
                                      .OrderBy(t => t.ItemSequence)
                               .Select(g => new{g.ItemSequence,g.AreaTitle})
                              ).FirstOrDefault()
```

And this is its result:

[image]

Now, I want to find areas that my `Order` passed so I changed above query to:

```
OrderItems.Include("NominalRoutings.OperationCatalog.WorkCenter.AreaSpecification")
          .Where(x=>x.Id == 799730)
          .Select(r=>r.NominalRoutings.Where(t => t.OperationCatalog.IsActive)
                                      .Select(t=>new
                                                    {
                                                     AreaTitle=t.OperationCatalog.WorkCenter.AreaSpecification.Title,
                                                     t.ItemSequence
                                                    })
                                      .OrderBy(t => t.ItemSequence)
                               .GroupBy(routing => routing.AreaTitle)
                               .Select(t=>t.Key)
                              ).FirstOrDefault()
```

The result is:

[image]

But I expect following result:

- 1 Melt
- 2 LAB
- 3 PU09
- 4 LSM

Because I orderd the areas by `ItemSequence` and then grouped it by Title. Am I mistaken? or there is any problem in my code?

Answer (score 0):

`OrderBy` returns an `IOrderedEnumerable` and obviously keeps the order but when using `GroupBy` it isn't required to keep any order (if it would it would have returned `IOrderedEnumerable` too to make it clear).

What I suggest you do is first `GroupBy` and then `Order`

```
.Select(t => new { AreaTitle = t.OperationCatalog.WorkCenter.AreaSpecification.Title, t.ItemSequence })
.GroupBy(routing => routing.AreaTitle)
.OrderBy(t => t.Min(x => x.ItemSequence))
.Select(t=>t.Key)
```